# Objective c - search by word

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nspredicate

I have a books app, where user can browse and search for books.
for example this is the list of books:

"Carrion Comfort"
"Cover Her Face"
"No Country for Old Men"
"The Monkey's Raincoat"

I want to implement a search mechanism that behave as follow:
if the user search for "**co**" the result will be:

"Carrion **Co**mfort"
"**Co**ver Her Face"
"No **Co**untry for Old Men"

you can notice that I only want to find the words beginning with "co", this is why the book "The Monkey's Raincoat" is not in the result although it contains "co"

To achieve that, I created a managed object called `Token`:

```
Token  
------
normalizedString
```

And I added a to-many relationship to my Book object

```
Book
-----
title  
releaseDate

tokens (to-many)
```

And now this is how my search predicate looks like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tokens, $token, $token.normalizedString BEGINSWITH[cd] %@).@count > 0", [searchString lowercaseString]];
```

This works fine if I search single words, for example if I search "Her" I get the result:
"Cover Her Face"

But when I try searching for more than one word, for example "Her Face", I dont get any results.

I understand why this is happening, but can't find the right solution here.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: What you apparently want is a KWIK index.  (Look it up.  There should be several algorithms proposed.)

Comment: It seems to me like you are trying to hit two birds with the same stone when you should be using two stones. When u user taps the space you no longer need to check for the prefix and instead only need to check contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I eventually tokenised the search string and created a more complex predicate to deal with those tokens:

```
- (NSPredicate *)predicateForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {    
    NSSet *searchTokens = [[Tokenizer sharedTokenizer] tokenize:searchString];

    NSMutableArray *subPreds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:searchTokens.count];
    for (NSString *token in searchTokens) {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tokens, $token, $token.normalizedString BEGINSWITH[cd] %@).@count > 0", token];
        [subPreds addObject:pred];
    }
    return [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[subPreds copy]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish solution I guess, but I would try to generate the tokens differently.
Instead of a token being just a word, it would start from a word and include the following text.

For "Cover Her Face"

Instead of

```
Cover
Her
Face
```

I would try to get the tokens:

```
Cover Her Face
Her Face
Face
```

Then the BEGINSWITH solution should work as you intended. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the books in an `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` of `NSString*`s... (sorry, I have no idea what `NSPredicate` is. But if you're able to convert your books to `NSString*`s then you could use this method)

```
NSMutableArray* books = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:   @"Carrion Comfort",
                                                            @"Cover Her Face",
                                                            @"No Country for Old Men",
                                                            @"The Monkey's Raincoat",
                                                            nil ];

[books enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray* _tmp = [(NSString*)obj componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    [_tmp enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([[_obj substringToIndex:2] isEqualTo:@"co"] ||
            [[_obj substringToIndex:2] isEqualTo:@"Co"])
            NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }];
}];
```

It might not be the most efficient way but it definitely works.

There must be a way to handle the case sensitivity other than providing every possible variations, but I didn't really have time to figure it out. Maybe convert everything to lowercase before comparing?